# Writing data to SQL database from ASP.NET textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database

When writing to an SQL database, I am receiving 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' rather than the actual data itself.

upload.aspx.cs file (containing the query):

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO reports (birdname, location, details, image, spotteddata, uploaddata, typeofbird) VALUES ('"+birdnametext+"', 'mygarden', 'some details about how long you waited', ' " + img + "', '10th March 2014','" + dateNow + "', '2')";
```

upload.aspx (containing the textbox):

```
<header> Upload </header>
<p> Please fill out the form below to put your item up for sale</p>
<p>  
<span>Name of Bird:
<asp:TextBox ID="birdnametext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </span>
<br/>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
<br />
```

Comment: study http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-value-of-HTML-Input-TextBox-in-ASPNet-code-behind-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries to aviod.

Comment: I see all the answers posted are suggesting you use AddWithValue. Since you are using a pass through query this approach can become problematic. You would want to specify the datatype explicitly because sometimes it will get it wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2):

Their are may things you are doing wrong:

1. You are trying to pass the TextBox itself to the database, you need to pass it's Text instead. That means `...'"+ birdnametext + "' ...` should be  `...'"+ birdnametext.Text + "' ...`
2. You are opening a wide door for [injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) through text queries, Use parameterised queries instead for this.

You can build the command like the following:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO reports(birdname, location) VALUES(@birdname, @location);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("query,con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@birdname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = birdnametext.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "mygarden";
// similarly you can add the rest of columns and parameters 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a TextBox to access its contents :

```
... + birdnametext.Text + ...
```

**Parameterization, Not Concatenation**

Additionally, when building queries, you do not want to use string concatenation as it can leave you vulnerable to things like SQL Injection and poor syntax. A better approach would be to use parameterization as seen below :

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("{your-connection-string}"))
{
     // Notice the use of parameters
     var query = "INSERT INTO reports (birdname, location, details, image, spotteddata, uploaddata, typeofbird) VALUES (@birdname, @location', @details, ' @uploadData, @someDate, @now, @x)";
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
     {
          connection.Open();
          // Read the bytes of your image here and store in a byte[]
          var imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(Image1.ImageUrl);
          // Add your parameters
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birdName",birdnametext.Text);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location","mygarden");
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details","some details about how long you waited");
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uploadData",imageData);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someDate","10th March 2014");
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now",DateTime.Now);        
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x",2);  
          // Execute your query
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change birdnametext to birdnametext.text in your sql statement